# Store a value in a list using a 'if'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing a Tic Tac Toe, in one of the stages I need to put a value in a list, but that value is not saved. Somebody help me? Where am I going wrong?

```
def jogadorO():
    jO = int(input("Insira um número para a escolha da posição dentro do tabuleiro: "))
    listO = [[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]

    if jO == 1: listO[0][0] = 'O'
    elif jO == 2: listO[0][1] = 'O'
    elif jO == 3: listO[0][2] = 'O'
    elif jO == 4: listO[1][0] = 'O'
    elif jO == 5: listO[1][1] = 'O'
    elif jO == 6: listO[1][2] = 'O'
    elif jO == 7: listO[2][0] = 'O'
    elif jO == 8: listO[2][1] = 'O'
    elif jO == 9: listO[2][2] = 'O'
    else: print('erro')
    print(listO)
```

I get add the value in the list, but it does not get saved, so when I try to put another value the first disappears and only the second stays.

Comment: You create a new list and assign it every function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the list global. and replace each value inside the function.

```
listO = [[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]

def jogadorO():

    global listO
    jO = int(input("Insira um número para a escolha da posição dentro do tabuleiro: "))

    if jO == 1: listO[0][0] = 'O'
    elif jO == 2: listO[0][1] = 'O'
    elif jO == 3: listO[0][2] = 'O'
    elif jO == 4: listO[1][0] = 'O'
    elif jO == 5: listO[1][1] = 'O'
    elif jO == 6: listO[1][2] = 'O'
    elif jO == 7: listO[2][0] = 'O'
    elif jO == 8: listO[2][1] = 'O'
    elif jO == 9: listO[2][2] = 'O'
    else: print('erro')
    print(listO)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i don't very payed attention this.

Comment: Has my answer solved your question? if it did please mark the answer as solved.
if not please post a little more of your code to help me understand better.